# Python: Binary Search - "Find the first occurrence"

Tags: python, python-3.x, computer-science

having a bit of trouble with this one. I have included what I have below. When I submit it, it keeps saying "Program timed out" for some reason. I am not sure what to do next. It works to a certain degree, ie, some tests work, not the last test just doesn't work. What do you suggest?

I have included a screenshot of the question, as well as what I have so far.

Here is the note (pseudocode) from class, I just need to modify this to modify it to print the first occurance of the target in the ordered_list. If the target does not exist in the list, it must return None.

Thank you in advance!!

The Question:
You are to write the code of a Python function

binsearch first(ordered list, target)

that, given a nonempty ordered list of items and a target item, all of the same type, returns the index of the ﬁrst occurrence of the target in the list, if the target is in the list, and None otherwise.

For example, the call binsearch first([1, 3, 3, 7, 9], 3) should return 1 since the ﬁrst 3 is at index 1. Similarly, the call binsearch first([1, 3, 3, 7, 9], 9) should return 4, and the call binsearch first([1, 3, 3, 7, 9], 5) should return None.

You may not assume anything about the type of the items, other than that they are orderable. For example, items could be strings and the call binsearch first(["Alice", "Bob", "Chloe", "Chloe", "Dave"], "Chloe") should return 2.

Your program will be evaluated for eﬃciency and style. For full credit, it may only make a single test for equality (it may only have a single “==” comparison which, additionally, may not be within any loop). That is, the only equality test happens at the end of execution, just before returning.

Restrictions: Recursion is not allowed for this problem. allowed to use any operations other than

Furthermore, you are not

- , − , // , × , < ,

and (once) ==

Of course, all builtins and library functions related to search are also disallowed: you have to do the coding yourself.

```html
def binsearch_first(ordered_list, target):
    left = 0
    right = len(ordered_list) - 1
    count = 0
    while left <= right:
        mid = (left + right) // 2
        count = count + 1
        if ordered_list[mid] == target:
            while mid > 0 and ordered_list[mid - 1] == target:
                mid = mid - 1
            return mid
        elif target < ordered_list[mid]:
            right = mid - 1
        else:
            left = mid + 1
    return None
```

[Find the first occurrence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoT0i.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Doing your homework? :-)

Comment: You can't use a `for` loop?

Comment: Yes doing my homework haha

Comment: Why do you have the count variable?

Comment: I believe you can use for loop. You just can't use == more than once (I have used it twice, unfortunately), you also can't import any libraries, you can't use recursion, and you can't use anything else other than + , − , // , × , < , and == (as mentioned, only once)

Comment: count variable was just for me, please ignore. It doesn't make much of a difference if it is there or not. I was using it for another assignment

Comment: The problem wants you to use only 1 '==' comparison during the entire algorithm for a binary search? There must be something wrong here.

Comment: Yup lol, only one ==

Comment: Here's something that may help, its in my notes, and I am supposed to convert it to Python code: 
N := len(A); L := 1; R := N; found := false;
while (L ≤ R) and (not found) do
   m := (L + R) div 2;
   if A[m] = x then found := true
     elsif A[m] < x then L := m+1
     else R := m-1
   end
end;
return found

Answer (score 1):

The only operator that works with string and integer is <.
We have to make use of the fact that it is an ordered list - arranged in increasing order.

```
def binsearch(orderedlist,target):
  candidate = 0
  for i in range(len(orderedlist)):
    if orderedlist[i] < target:
      candidate = candidate
    else:
      if i+1 < len(orderedlist):
        if orderedlist[i] < orderedlist[i+1]:
          #it is an ordered list so if i+1 is not bigger than i, it must be equal
          candidate = candidate
        else:
          candidate = i
          break # can you use break?
  if orderedlist[candidate] == target:
    return candidate
  else:
    return None
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not a CS student hence cannot comment on the effectiveness of the program, but you can achieve your goal by using a simple `for` loop

```
def binsearch_first(ordered_list, target):
    i=0
    for ele in ordered_list:
        if ele == target:
            return i 
            break
        else:
            i+=1
    return None
```

Result of this is:

```
>>> binsearch_first([1, 3, 3, 7, 9], 3)
1
>>> binsearch_first(["Alice", "Bob", "Chloe", "Chloe", "Dave"], "Chloe")
2
```

Regards

Comment: cant use enumerate unfortunately :(

Comment: Updated the Answer , please check

Comment: so i think it should also return none if the target does not exist in the ordered_list

Comment: Updated the answer again!. Mark it correct if it solved your problem! Thanks

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working, sorry :(
for your reference, I have included the Pseudocode I learned in class above

Comment: What do you mean by not working ? I have attached the result also! Can you let me know for which inputs it didn't work ?

Comment: The equality test should not be in the loop?

Comment: But I clearly see , the equality is being tested in the OP's post :(

Comment: If your for loop runs more than once and the equality is inside the for loop then it is considered as more than 1 equality test?

Comment: Can I use dictionaries?